# Create variables inside an each loop in a pug template

Tags: loops, express, variables, pug

How can I create variables inside a loop in pug and call them later?

I passed a variable *words* from an express js server to a pug template and I looped through the variable:

```
  each word, index in words
    - var spelling = #{word['orth']};
    - var pronunciation = #{word['pron']};
```

Then I tried to call the variables:

```
  ul
     #{spelling}
```

I have this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all these unnecessary characters when access `word` inside the each loop.

```
  each word, index in words
    - var spelling = word.orth;
    - var pronunciation = word.pron;
```

Comment: It's not giving me the error message anymore but it's not printing out the variable's contents either. When I call spelling for example, all I get is the bullet for the list li. I removed the #{} when I called spelling and still nothing.

Comment: Thanks it's working now.  The problem was with the indentation when I call the variable.