# if else inside a loop in pug

Tags: loops, express, if-statement, pug

This is a follow-up question to [Create variables inside an each loop in a pug template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604403/create-variables-inside-an-each-loop-in-a-pug-template/47606194#47606194)

I have a problem with a simple if else inside a loop in pug.
This is my code:

```
 extends layout
 block content
 h2 #{item}
 each word, index in words
  - var spelling = word.orth;
  if(item == spelling)
   p #{spelling}
  else
   p does not exist yet
```

The problem is if a word exists, it prints it out correctly **but it also prints** *does not exist yet* with it. And if a word does not exist, it prints out *does not exist yet*  **3 times** (That's the number of words I have in the xml file I am searching, see below).

Background: I am searching through an xml file for words. The variable *item* is the user input, the word we are looking for in the xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 extends layout
 block content
 h2 #{item}
 - var found = 0
 each word, index in words
  - var spelling = word.orth;
  if(item == spelling)
   - found = 1
   p #{spelling}
  else if (found == 0 && index == words.length -1)
   p does not exist yet
```